# JodaTime Integer Min/Max Value parsing

Tags: java, jodatime

Can someone give me some information about this parsing behavior of JodaTime?

```
String minValueString = new DateTime(Long.MIN_VALUE).toString();
System.out.println(minValueString);
DateTime minDateTime = DateTime.parse(minValueString);
System.out.println(minDateTime.toString());
```

prints this,

```
-292275055-05-16T17:40:32.192+00:53:28
```

but throws this Exception for the parsing part

```
org.joda.time.IllegalFieldValueException: Cannot parse "-292275055-05-16T17:40:32.192+00:53:28": Value -292275055 for year must be in the range [-292275054,292278993]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Java 8's JSR310 (based on JodaTime) has a DateTime.MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE and the behaviour outside this range is not supported (as @Magnilex pointed out).

> LocalDateTime.of( ... )
>
> **throws**
>
> DateTimeException - if the value of any field is out of range, or if the day-of-month is invalid for the month-year

I suggest you migration to JSR-310 if you can.  It is built in to Java 8 and there is a backport for earlier version.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html

The problem with the example above is that the start of the year `-292275054-01-01` is out side the range so it cannot store this value so it parse the rest of the date.  It could do this in theory with special handling but since this is a date before the dinosaurs lived and less than MIN_VALUE, you shouldn't expect it to be valid.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit how the Java 8 API handles these situations? Does it throw an exception or is the behaviour defined in some other way? Or doesn't it have the limitation at all?

Comment: @Magnilex The behaviour out side the range is undefined which means it could be different between updates of Java or possibly even locales. (I suspect it isn't but what ever it happens to do you shouldn't depend on it)

Comment: And whats the Joda DateTime minimum/maximum? How to create a minimum/maximum object?

Comment: @heaphach JodaTime isn't specific about this, but there must be a sane year you consider to low to be valid. e.g. do you need dates before the present, 1970, 1900, 0000, or -9999, or -99999999

Comment: @PeterLawrey Is it really undefined in the `LocalDateTime` API? As far as I can tell, it throws an exception if the value is too large/small. E.g. `LocalDateTime.ofEpochSecond(Long.MIN_VALUE, 0, ZoneOffset.UTC)` throws _Invalid value for Year (valid values -999999999 - 999999999): -292277022657_. In other words, the Java 8 equivalent code of OP's code fails on the first row, all according to the JavaDoc.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I don't think that JodaTime has the DateTime.MIN_VALUE and MAX_VALUE you mention in the first sentence. If they do could you link that to the documentation?

Comment: @Tyler you are right, it not clear that I confused it with JSR 310 which is based on JodaTime.